# Class '_JsonQuerySnapshot' has no instance method '[]' flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to show "No posts" text when database don't have any posts (length = 0)
(Database's post type is list)

When I use this code, it shows error

Error here :

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════

```
Class '_JsonQuerySnapshot' has no instance method '[]'.
Receiver: Instance of '_JsonQuerySnapshot'
Tried calling: []("posts")
```

My code here:

```
return StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("users")
            // .orderBy('datePublished', descending: true)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            if (snapshot.data['posts'].length != 0) {
              return showWidget();
            } else {
              return Container(
                child: Center(child: Text("No posts")),
              );
            }
          } else {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.red),
            );
          }
        });
```

Comment: how many items in post (list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're trying to get snapshots for a whole collection with :

```
   FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .snapshots(),
```

this will return a `QuerySnapshot` which will contain the `docs` list, so you need to iterate over them to check:

```
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        // .orderBy('datePublished', descending: true)
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        final isCollectionEmpty = snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty;
        final DocumentsWhichContainsPosts = snapshot.data!.docs.where((doc) => (doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)["posts"].isNotEmpty);
        if (DocumentsWhichContainsPosts.isNotEmpty) {
          return showWidget();
        } else {
          return Container(
            child: Center(child: Text("No posts")),
          );
        }
      } else {
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.red),
        );
      }
    });
```

Comment: error show like this,
type '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast

Comment: sorry my mistake, wait I will edit

Comment: try now the code I changed doc to doc.data()